# How to avoid this pesky indexoutofboundsexception - Adding items to JSON Array

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-volley

My app crashes because I get of INDEXOUTOFBOUNDSEXCEPTION.

item = feedItems.get(position); is what's out of bounds.

I have this JSON file saved on my SERVER:

```
{
    "feed": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Atlanta",
            "image": "http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1716876/thumbs/o-ATLANTA-TRAFFIC-facebook.jpg",
            "status": "\"Enter here to start chatting.\"",
            "profilePic": "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/dubchat.png",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": null
        },


        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Chicago",
            "image": "http://www.sagaftra.org/files/sag/branch_photos/chicago_banner.jpg",
            "status": "30 years of Cirque du Soleil's best photos",
            "profilePic": "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/dubchat.png",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": "http://ti.me/1qW8MLB"
        },

          {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Los Angelos",
            "image": "http://www.wordexpress.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Los-Angeles.jpg",
            "status": "A team of Austrian scientists has developed a laser system that causes fruit flies to dance.",
            "profilePic": "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/dubchat.png",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": "http://dsc.tv/xmMxD"
        },


        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Houston",
            "image": "http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/04/bf/13/3c/inn-at-the-ballpark.jpg",
            "status": "Android Sliding Menu using Navigation Drawer",
            "profilePic": "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/dubchat.png",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": "http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/"
        },

        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Miami",
             "image": "http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1477351/thumbs/o-SKYRISE-MIAMI-OBSERVATION-TOWER-facebook.jpg",
            "status": "That some achieve great success, is proof to all that others can achieve it as well",
            "profilePic": "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/dubchat.png",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": null
        },  
        {
            "id": 6 ,
            "name": "Las Vegas",
            "image": "http://www.tinaalberino.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/vegas-burj-al-arab.jpg",
            "status": "\"The Beast\" KTM 1290 Super Duke",
            "profilePic": "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/dubchat.png",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": ""
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "New York",
            "image": "http://www.burgessyachts.com/media/adminforms/locations/n/e/new_york_1.jpg",
            "status": "Weâ€™re assembling riders of every style, bike, and passion. If you ride with conviction, ride with us. You have 24 days to get ready for World Ride. Prepare by visiting:",
            "profilePic": "http://clxxxii.vm-host.net/clxxxii/dubchat.png",
            "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
            "url": "http://bit.ly/1wmBWaN"
        } 

    ]
}
```

I have used these tutorials.

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-2/

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/

Here's the "custom adapter" that I've tweaked below. The adapter class of the messenger app doesn't run out of entries. The socket server continues to display the texts the the users send to to the server. In the Facebook tutorial, it's adapter only hold only four entries. So When I combines the adapters, I've gotten the message to appear on the Facebook status message. The problem is when you send more than 7 messages, the app crashes because the length of the JSON file entries.

So when I implement this little code.

```
if (position >= 6) {
            position = 0;

        }
```

It resets the position to 0 but it only when I send a message the server, the app won't crash anymore, meaning I can send more than 7 messages. The problem here is that the status message will only show the first message I typed. Meaning anything I type after the 7th entry won't show.

item = feedItems.get(position); is what's out of bounds.

```
public class MessagesListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private Context context;
    private List<Message> messagesItems;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;

    MediaPlayer mp;
    NetworkImageView profilePic;
    FeedImageView feedImageView;
    TextView name;
    FeedItem item;
    String postitionINDEX;

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public MessagesListAdapter(Context context, List<Message> navDrawerItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.messagesItems = navDrawerItems;

    }

    public MessagesListAdapter(Context context, List<Message> navDrawerItems,
            List<FeedItem> feedItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.messagesItems = navDrawerItems;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }

    public int getCountFeed() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    public Object getItemFeed(int location) {

        return feedItems.get(location);

    }

    public long getItemIdFeed(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return messagesItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return messagesItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        /**
         * The following list not implemented reusable list items as list items
         * are showing incorrect data Add the solution if you have one
         * */




        Message m = messagesItems.get(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Identifying the message owner
        if (messagesItems.get(position).isSelf()) {
            // message belongs to you, so load the right aligned layout
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_arrived,
                    null);

        } else {
            // message belongs to other person, load the left aligned layout
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message_sent,
                    null);

        }

        TextView lblFrom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblMsgFrom);
        TextView txtMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);

        // txtMsg.setText(m.getMessage());

        txtMsg.setText(Integer.toString(position));

        lblFrom.setText(m.getFromName());

        //
        //
        //
        //
        //

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

        name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView timestamp = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
        TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txtStatusMsg);
        TextView url = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtUrl);
        profilePic = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        feedImageView = (FeedImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.feedImage1);

        // postitionINDEX = feedItems.get(position).getStatus();
        // postitionINDEX = Integer.toString(feedItems.get(position).getId() +
        // 1);
        // statusMsg.setText(m.getMessage());

        item = feedItems.get(position);

        // statusMsg.setText(postitionINDEX);

        // name.setText(item.getName());

        // final int ok234 = messagesItems.indexOf(1);
        // int index = feedItems.indexOf("papa"); // index = 2

        // name.setText(Integer.toString(ok234));

        // name.setText(Integer.toString(item.getId()));
        // Converting timestamp into x ago format
        CharSequence timeAgo = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
                Long.parseLong(item.getTimeStamp()),
                System.currentTimeMillis(), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);
        timestamp.setText(timeAgo);

        // Chcek for empty status message
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getStatus())) {
            statusMsg.setText(m.getMessage());
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // status is empty, remove from view
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Checking for null feed url
        if (item.getUrl() != null) {
            url.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + item.getUrl() + "\">"
                    + item.getUrl() + "</a> "));

            // Making url clickable
            url.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

            // URL HIDDEN FOR NOW
            url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            // url is null, remove from the view
            url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // user profile pic
        profilePic.setImageUrl(item.getProfilePic(), imageLoader);

        // Feed image
        if (item.getImge() != null) {
            feedImageView.setImageUrl(item.getImge(), imageLoader);
            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            feedImageView
                    .setResponseObserver(new FeedImageView.ResponseObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                    });
        } else {

            feedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        profilePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                switch (item.getId()) {

                case 1:

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.cameraflash);
                    mp.setVolume(100, 100);
                    mp.start();

                    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(context, NameActivity.class);
                    myIntent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(myIntent1);

                    break;

                case 2:

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.cameraflash);
                    mp.setVolume(100, 100);
                    mp.start();

                    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(context, NameActivity.class);
                    myIntent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(myIntent2);

                    break;
                case 3:

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.cameraflash);
                    mp.setVolume(100, 100);
                    mp.start();

                    Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(context, NameActivity.class);
                    myIntent3.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    context.startActivity(myIntent3);

                    break;
                }

            }
        });

        feedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

This is the JSON parsing method in the Activity that hosts the adapter class.

```
private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");



for (i5 = 0; i5 < feedArray.length(); i5++) {
        JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i5);

        FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
        item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
        item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

        // Image might be null sometimes
        String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                .getString("image");
        item.setImge(image);
        item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
        item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
        item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

        // url might be null sometimes
        String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                .getString("url");
        item.setUrl(feedUrl);

        feedItems.add(item);

    }
    //
    i5 = 0;
    // notify data changes to list adapater
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Either I can change each entry in the JSON object and then continue to add items to the JSON file. Or I cannot use the JSON file and create a dynamic file that never ends and is erased when you leave the app. Does anyone know a good way of solving this app?

Comment: In which line getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK item = feedItems.get(position); is what's out of bounds.

Comment: return `feedItems.size()` from `getCount()`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 0.  ---- on this line. Message m = messagesItems.get(position);